How to convert UTC to local time in SQL Server
We have a database where events are tracked with a datetime field in UTC.  That's great for accuracy, but it's hard to relate to non-technical users, or to match to events like files being written, which are timestamped in the local time.  For example, when exporting an order, we need to determine on which day the order was entered.



OrderHeaderID
CustomerID
LastModified
CreatedBy




0E8B2F2F-6D7A-40DF-87CD-B00EF4801F07
EXQHA
2024-07-23 14:35:46.000
10094:sreiley


D28EB7C4-7CB0-4347-8D5E-CC4D07A657D8
SHOLFA
2024-07-23 14:34:30.000
10094:cstaykov



In US Central Time, the date matches the UTC date from midnight to 6:00 or 7:00 PM (depending on Daylight Savings Time).  But between those hours and midnight, UTC is one day ahead, and that affects our commitment to deliver product within two business days.  So we need to convert to local time.
How can I do this?

Why not just use AT TIME ZONE? Example.

SELECT @nnfield = 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(MINUTE, (CAST(SUBSTRING(current_utc_offset, 1, 
        CHARINDEX(':', current_utc_offset) -1) AS INT) * 60) 
        + CAST(SUBSTRING(current_utc_offset, CHARINDEX(':', current_utc_offset) + 1, 2) AS INTEGER), 
        LastModified), 101) 
FROM 
    sys.time_zone_info 
WHERE 
    name = 'Central Standard Time'

sys.time_zone_info is a table of world time zones, their offset from UTC, and whether or not they are currently in Daylight Savings Time.



name
current_utc_offset
is_currently_dst




Yukon Standard Time
-07:00
0


Central America Standard Time
-06:00
0


Central Standard Time
-05:00
1


Easter Island Standard Time
-06:00
0



You can use the DATEADD function to apply the current_utc_offset to your stored time.
The problem is that the current_utc_offset is a string.  So we need to convert that to a number. Also, we can't just assume that -5:00 converts to -5, as some times zones, like Sri Lanka Standard Time, are offset from UTC by a value that includes a number of minutes.
Using CHARINDEX to grab the location of the semi-colon that separates the hour portion from the minutes portion, we use SUBSTRING to break the string into an hours and a minutes portion.  We cast those values as integers and then multiply the hours integer by 60.  We add that to the minutes portion and get a number of minutes to add or subtract from the time field.
I then convert this into the date format that I want: MM/DD/YYYY.
And all this to make sure that orders created between 6:00 PM and midnight are assigned to the proper day.

Why is this the solution? It's so long winded...
